# Xamarin Android GC get stuck

Tags: xamarin, garbage-collection, xamarin.android

My application hang after some repeated user actions. 
At the beginning I see GC output:

```
05-18 14:48:05.599 I/art     ( 2985): Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 25278(1141KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 21% free, 14MB/18MB, paused 610us total 23.887ms
05-18 14:48:05.606 D/Mono    ( 2985): GC_TAR_BRIDGE bridges 3478 objects 3478 opaque 0 colors 3478 colors-bridged 3478 colors-visible 3478 xref 0 cache-hit 0 cache-semihit 0 cache-miss 0 setup 0.29ms tarjan 0.46ms scc-setup 0.29ms gather-xref 0.04ms xref-setup 0.02ms cleanup 0.19ms
05-18 14:48:05.606 D/Mono    ( 2985): GC_BRIDGE: Complete, was running for 36.70ms
05-18 14:48:05.606 D/Mono    ( 2985): GC_MINOR: (Nursery full) time 10.47ms, stw 11.24ms promoted 534K major size: 7568K in use: 6770K los size: 4252K in use: 3668K
05-18 14:48:10.670 I/art     ( 2985): Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 25789(1168KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 20% free, 15MB/19MB, paused 645us total 25.123ms
05-18 14:48:10.677 D/Mono    ( 2985): GC_TAR_BRIDGE bridges 3335 objects 3335 opaque 0 colors 3335 colors-bridged 3335 colors-visible 3335 xref 0 cache-hit 0 cache-semihit 0 cache-miss 0 setup 0.09ms tarjan 0.43ms scc-setup 0.31ms gather-xref 0.04ms xref-setup 0.02ms cleanup 0.16ms
05-18 14:48:10.677 D/Mono    ( 2985): GC_BRIDGE: Complete, was running for 37.47ms
05-18 14:48:10.677 D/Mono    ( 2985): GC_MINOR: (Nursery full) time 9.10ms, stw 9.85ms promoted 519K major size: 8112K in use: 7290K los size: 4252K in use: 3668K
05-18 14:48:14.784 I/art     ( 2985): Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 25119(1142KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 19% free, 16MB/20MB, paused 673us total 26.589ms
05-18 14:48:14.791 D/Mono    ( 2985): GC_TAR_BRIDGE bridges 3367 objects 3367 opaque 0 colors 3367 colors-bridged 3367 colors-visible 3367 xref 0 cache-hit 0 cache-semihit 0 cache-miss 0 setup 0.09ms tarjan 0.45ms scc-setup 0.28ms gather-xref 0.04ms xref-setup 0.02ms cleanup 0.16ms
05-18 14:48:14.791 D/Mono    ( 2985): GC_BRIDGE: Complete, was running for 38.79ms
05-18 14:48:14.791 D/Mono    ( 2985): GC_MINOR: (Nursery full) time 9.61ms, stw 10.30ms promoted 523K major size: 8624K in use: 7814K los size: 4252K in use: 3668K
```

After some time, the application hangs and I see a lot of such lines in the log:

```
05-18 14:48:15.589 I/monodroid-gc( 2985): 46080 outstanding GREFs. Performing a full GC!
05-18 14:48:15.685 I/art     ( 2985): Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 10815(715KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 19% free, 16MB/20MB, paused 389us total 23.169ms
05-18 14:48:16.107 D/Mono    ( 2985): GC_TAR_BRIDGE bridges 45917 objects 46071 opaque 842 colors 45915 colors-bridged 45915 colors-visible 45915 xref 369 cache-hit 0 cache-semihit 0 cache-miss 0 setup 0.86ms tarjan 6.34ms scc-setup 3.96ms gather-xref 0.40ms xref-setup 0.09ms cleanup 1.96ms
05-18 14:48:16.108 D/Mono    ( 2985): GC_BRIDGE: Complete, was running for 487.45ms
05-18 14:48:16.108 D/Mono    ( 2985): GC_MAJOR: (user request) time 25.62ms, stw 28.16ms los size: 4252K in use: 1631K
05-18 14:48:16.108 D/Mono    ( 2985): GC_MAJOR_SWEEP: major size: 6128K in use: 4929K
05-18 14:48:16.990 I/monodroid-gc( 2985): 46080 outstanding GREFs. Performing a full GC!
05-18 14:48:17.085 I/art     ( 2985): Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 4804(222KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 19% free, 16MB/20MB, paused 513us total 24.407ms
05-18 14:48:17.140 D/Mono    ( 2985): GC_TAR_BRIDGE bridges 45919 objects 45983 opaque 291 colors 45917 colors-bridged 45917 colors-visible 45917 xref 175 cache-hit 0 cache-semihit 0 cache-miss 0 setup 0.86ms tarjan 6.48ms scc-setup 3.75ms gather-xref 0.41ms xref-setup 0.09ms cleanup 1.97ms
05-18 14:48:17.140 D/Mono    ( 2985): GC_BRIDGE: Complete, was running for 121.70ms
05-18 14:48:17.140 D/Mono    ( 2985): GC_MAJOR: (user request) time 26.42ms, stw 28.16ms los size: 4252K in use: 1631K
05-18 14:48:17.140 D/Mono    ( 2985): GC_MAJOR_SWEEP: major size: 6128K in use: 4931K
05-18 14:48:17.147 I/monodroid-gc( 2985): 46080 outstanding GREFs. Performing a full GC!
05-18 14:48:17.257 I/art     ( 2985): Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 125(5KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 19% free, 16MB/20MB, paused 852us total 34.530ms
05-18 14:48:17.713 D/Mono    ( 2985): GC_TAR_BRIDGE bridges 45935 objects 45999 opaque 291 colors 45933 colors-bridged 45933 colors-visible 45933 xref 175 cache-hit 0 cache-semihit 0 cache-miss 0 setup 0.86ms tarjan 6.64ms scc-setup 3.62ms gather-xref 0.40ms xref-setup 0.09ms cleanup 2.13ms
05-18 14:48:17.713 D/Mono    ( 2985): GC_BRIDGE: Complete, was running for 539.05ms
05-18 14:48:17.713 D/Mono    ( 2985): GC_MAJOR_SWEEP: major size: 6128K in use: 4835K
05-18 14:48:17.713 D/Mono    ( 2985): GC_MAJOR: (user request) time 24.92ms, stw 26.12ms los size: 4252K in use: 1579K
```

It's seems that GC try to free resources but can't. What objects are trying to destroy?
Can someone explain to me what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

The entries in the log you posted are for GC (Garbage Collection), i.e. reclaiming memory from objects no longer in use on the heap.

There are 2 types of GC's hapening there:

1) android runtime GC (denoted by "I/art ")

2) MONO/.NET runtime GC ( denoted by "D/Mono" )

Each runtime (Android vs. .NET/Mono) has it's own managed memory heap it is responsible for cleaning up to make sure no memory "leaks".

It does appear that GC is occurring extremely frequently, and so the app is likely waiting on GC, which is constantly occurring.